# Issue using a ListView inside a FormView

Tags: swift, swiftui

Essentially I would like to add a section to my Form that is a dynamic list, why doesn't this work inside a Form, any workaround?

```
        Form {
            Section("My List") {
                ForEach(list, id: \.self) { listItem in
                    Text(listItem.name)
                }
                .onAppear {
                    APICalls().getData(url: "https://test.com") { (info: [Couriers], _) in
                        self.list = info
                        if list == [] {
                            print("No Data")
                        } else {
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move the `.onAppear(...)` outside the `Form`, like this (works for me)

```
var body: some View {
    Form {
        Section("My List") {
            ForEach(list, id: \.self) { listItem in
                Text(listItem.name)
            }
        }
    }
    .onAppear {
        APICalls().getData(url: "https://test.com") { (info: [Couriers], _) in
            self.list = info
            if list == [] {
                print("No Data")
            } else {
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Understood, thank you. If you don't mind can you please take a look at this other question. Very curious how this can be achieved. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74168164/how-to-achieve-a-split-view-navigation-style-in-swiftui?noredirect=1#comment130949034_74168164